# Toggle class of Table Row

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a javascript that will toggle the class of a table row on the onClick event so that I can use css to change the look and functionality of it, however I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.

The goal is to have a table in which users can select a row and have it highlight, and should they select another row the previous selection return to its original class.  The table rows have alternating colors, and I am unsure how to get this to work the way I like.

The 3 css classes are:
evn
odd
selected

A row can only be 1 of the 2:

```
<script>
function toggle(elem) {
  selectClass = 'selected';
  orgClass = document.getElementById(elem).className;
  elem.className = (elem.className == 'selectClass)?orgClass:selectClass;
}
</script>
<table>
<tr class='evn' id=0 name='rowsel' tabindex=0 onClick='toggle(this);'>
  <td>something</td>
  <td>something else</td>
</tr>
<tr class='odd' id=1 name='rowsel' tabindex=0 onClick='toggle(this);'>
  <td>something</td>
  <td>something else</td>
</tr>
<tr class='evn' id=2 name='rowsel' tabindex=0 onClick='toggle(this);'>
  <td>something</td>
  <td>something else</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't like it when people answer JavaScript questions with jQuery answers, so I ticked him off for it, but Paniyar is right that doing things like this is a **lot** easier (or at least more concise) if you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Might be worth checking out. (Those names are links, btw, stoopid SO policy of making links far too subtle, grumble, growl...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to:

1. Remove the selected class from the previously selected element (if it was set)
2. Add it to the current selection.

something like this would do it:

```
    function toggle(elem) {
        var allelems = document.getElementsByClassName( "odd" );
        for (var i = 0; i < allelems.length; i++ )
        {
            allelems[i].className = allelems[i].className.replace( "selected", "" );
        }
        var allelems = document.getElementsByClassName( "evn" );
        for (var i = 0; i < allelems.length; i++ )
        {
            allelems[i].className = allelems[i].className.replace( "selected", "" );
        }

        elem.className += " selected";
    }
```

The above could be hugely improved! It works but consider it more as pseudo-code for illustration.

Answer (score 2):

By using jquery its simple.

```
$("tr").removeClass("selected"); // Removes 'selected' class from all tr element
$("#id2").addClass("selected"); // adds 'selected' class to #id2 element
```

For more info [addclass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [remove class](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

**EDIT**

Without using jquery you can do like as follows.

```
 function toggle(elem){
  trele=document.getElementById('tblid').getElementsByTagName('TR');
  var classname;
  for(var i=0;i<trele.length;i++)
  {
   classname=trele[i].className;
   trele[i].className=classname.replace("selected","");
  }
  elem.className+=' selected';
 }
```

note : set id for your table as tblid

Comment: This does however, require jQuery.

Comment: @Martijn: toggleClass is tricky because it assumes a certain state and toggles that. But what if you select a row twice? addClass+addClass = addClass, but toggleClass+toggleClass = 0 :-D

Comment: @Jochem one could argue whether one is really toggling in that case ;)

Comment: @Martijn true, but if I read the question, I don't think it is really about toggling (I think the function-name in the code is misleading, or I am misinterpreting the question)

Comment: I dont have the option of JQuery unfortunately, the server in which I am writing this for is running a very specific application and those responsible for it understandably do not want to put any additional software on it that may cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't replace the `odd` or `evn` classes with `selected`. An element may have more than 1 classes so add the `selected` class so you would have `odd selected` when selected and just `odd` when not selected. Use `indexOf` on the `className` property to see if the element has the `selected` class or not. Add it with `+= ' selected'` and remove it with `replace`.

Note that this requires you to change you class definition for `selected` a little, but this is the right way to do what you need.